# The program called by the init.d works by itself, but not when the init.d itself runs

Tags: bash, init-script, init.d

I currently have two programs, `my_sql_auto_update.sh` and `my_sql_auto_update_initd.sh`, the latter is the init.d script located at `~/etc/init.d/` which [should] run the `my_sql_auto_update.sh`.

The contents of `my_sql_auto_update_initd.sh` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#chkconfig: 2345 95 05

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

NAME=mysql_auto_update.sh
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
DAEMON=/home/3kstc/start_up_job/mysql_autoupdate/$NAME

#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
# 

start() 
{
    start-stop-daemon -S -o -q -m -b -p $PIDFILE -a $DAEMON 
    log_daemon_msg "Started auto-updating website"
}

stop() 
{
  start-stop-daemon -K -o -q -m -p $PIDFILE --name $NAME 
  log_daemon_msg "Stopped auto-updating website"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
       start
        ;;
    stop|force-stop)
       stop
        ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|restart|stop}"
esac    

exit 0
```

When I run the `mysql_auto_update.sh` program by itself *ie* from the terminal - it works without any problem.

**Q:**  Is there something missing in my init.d script that I've missed, or any other mistakes which could prevent it from working. As my `mysql_auto_update.sh` works by itself, the problem [I suspect] lies with the above code. Any help is highly appreciated!

**Additional Information:**
With my mysql_auto_update.sh I send out out the timestamp of the update as well to the website. So I can see when the last update has been. The time stamps haven't been changing, and also the website has not been getting the new information as it should.

When I run the `my_sql_auto_update_initd.sh` it prints out `"Started auto-updating website"` thus I know `start()` subroutine works. But alas the website doesn't get updates It's really perplexing. Any suggestion Wurtel would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using a modified initd or not, but those start and stop functions should be JUST start() and stop().

Comment: Here's a [reference](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html).

Comment: @3kstc Is `~/etc/init.d` a typo? Did you run `update-rc.d` ?

Comment: So what does happen when you run the init.d script? You do know that "It doesn't work" is not a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @wurtel With my `mysql_auto_update.sh` I send out out the timestamp of the update as well to the website. So I can see when the last update has been. The time stamps haven't been changing, and also the website has not been getting the new information as it should.

When I run the `my_sql_auto_update_initd.sh` it prints out `"Started auto-updating website"` thus I know `start()` subroutine works. But alas the website doesn't get updates It's really perplexing. Any suggestion Wurtel would be highly appreciated!

Comment: All you know is that the init.d script is going through the motions, have you checked that the mysql_auto_update.sh script is actually started? All I can recommend at this point is to ensure that you ensure that the script does error checking everywhere and logs any anomalities to a file (preferably together with a timestamp). *Never* assume anything.